How to set a custom ProductVersion in a WiX Bootstrapper project?
In my WiX Bootstrapper project, I can define the version of the Bundle using the Version attribute of the Bundle element. Here's an example:
<Bundle Name="Sample" Manufacturer="Sample Ltd." Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="5fffcf4d-b3e4-4eba-a850-ab8ab3fe501d">
</Bundle>

The value of the Version attribute is then used for the FileVersion and ProductVersion fields in the final .exe file.
We need to set ProductVersion to a custom value, such as 1.0.0.0 cs203948. Is that possible? Currently, we use the tool ResourceHacker to modify the ProductVersion afterward, but the tool is causing issues (e.g., "Out of memory" errors on local machines). Therefore, we would like to eliminate the need for it.
UPDATE 1:
It seems that's not supported, see method UpdateBurnResources. So I have to change the ProductVersion afterwards.
Tools I have already tried:

ResourceHacker: Does still work in virtual machines, but not on normal ones (I'm trying to contact the developer)
ResourceTuner: Does work, but it's not free and I don't really know how to license, cause I would integrate usage in MSBuild which runs on n computers.
RCEdit: Breaks the executable
WinAPI method UpdateResourceA: Breaks the executable

UPDATE 2:

StampVer: Only supports format "X.X.X.X"

Thanks in advance!

Most resource editor tools will strip off or break the payload. Try to detach the bootstrapper, manipulate it's version resource and then reattach it, which is supported through WiX toolset commands. E. g. using the WiX dotnet tool: dotnet wix burn detach ... and dotnet wix burn reattach .... Pass parameter -? to learn about exact commandline.

@zett42 You pointed me to the right direction. In Wix3 it's possible to "activate" some special MSBuild Targets by setting the MSBuild Property SignOutput to true (as described here). We already used this approach for signing, so it's the perfect place for setting our custom ProductVersion too because there the engine is still on it's own, without the payload and so ResourceHacker doesn't have a memory issue.

See comments on the original post.

Glad to be helpful. If you want this Q&A be even more helpful for future visitors, I suggest you move the text of your comment into this answer, which makes it easier to read and helps search engines. Feel free to use text from my comment as well.
